# 2次元リストから特定の要素を探し出し、その位置を表示させたい

Tags: python, python3, array

```
2d_array = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

上記のようなリストから最終的に`'(1,2)'`という結果をプリントしたいです。

試しに別のリストを作り上のarrayからそれぞれの要素を追加してから1を探し出し、5番目にあるという結果は得られたのですがそこから(1,2)というにはたどり着けませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 冗長ではありますが、`[x for x in [(i, l.index(1)) if 1 in l else -1 for i,l in enumerate(array_2d)] if x != -1]` など。

Comment: 5番目まで得られてるなら、`idx = 5` として `divmod(idx, 3)` ですね。 `(idx // 3, idx % 3)  = (1, 2)` を得られます。

Answer (score 2):

NumPy を使ってよければ、[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.sort.html) を使って次のように書けます。この方法は目的の要素が入っている場所を全列挙します。

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> ind = np.where(np.array(arr) == 1)
>>> ind
(array([1]), array([2]))
>>> # もしくは:
... (ind[0][0], ind[1][0])
(1, 2)
```

生の Python で関数を作るとしたら、たとえば単ににループを使って下のように書けます。こちらは目的の要素が入っている最初の場所を見つけます。

```
>>> def find2d(lst, elem):
...     for i, row in enumerate(lst):
...         for j, e in enumerate(row):
...             if e == elem:
...                 return i, j
...   return -1, -1  # 目的の要素が無かったときの処理です
... 
>>> arr = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> find2d(arr, 1)
(1, 2)
```

ただしどちらの方法も、`True` が要素に入っていると誤検出されるので注意してください (Python3 では `True == 1` [である](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764017/5989200)ため)。

Comment: try except はコストの大きな処理な上、この用途では頻繁に例外が発生するので、ここでの利用は避けるべきです。if 文を使ったほうがいいでしょう。

Comment: @夢先案内人 さん、確かにそうですね。単に for を二重で使った形に書き直しました。ありがとうございます。